# Why does a for-loop to resize an image run well at $A$1 but otherwise gives a height and/or width of 0?

Tags: excel, vba

My code resizes an image. If the image's TopLeftCell is $A$1, it will work. However, if it is any other cell the width or height ends up being 0.

It is supposed to be running through two functions: getCellHeight and getCellWidth to grab the total height and width of merged cells, but it will also work with non-merged cells as long as the TopLeftCell is $A$1.

**When working with non-merged cells:**

> Anything $A$n where n is greater than 1 results in a width with 0
>   height.
>
> Anything $(n)$1 where n is greater than A results in a height with 0
>   width.
>
> Anything $(n)$(m) where n is greater than A and m is greater than 1
>   results in 0 height and 0 width.

**When working with merged cells:**

*The functionality is similar to non-merged cells, the difference being that on $(n)$(m) it will only run the height and width for loops if:*

> The number of rows merged is >= 9. At 9 rows, the for loop for
>   counting rows will run a single time.
>
> The number of columns merged is >= 7. At 7 columns, the for loop for
>   counting columns will run a single time.
>
> Anything below 9 rows results in 0 height, anything below 7 rows
>   results in 0 width.

**Here is the code:**

```vb
Sub TestCode()
    If TypeOf Selection Is Picture Then
        Call ResizeSingleImage(Selection)
    ElseIf TypeOf Selection Is DrawingObjects Then
        Call ResizeMultipleImages(Selection)
    ElseIf TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox ("Please make sure an image is selected.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Function ResizeMultipleImages(ByRef refPictures)
    For Each refPic In refPictures
        Call ResizeSingleImage(refPic)
    Next
End Function

Function ResizeSingleImage(ByRef refPicture)
    refPicture.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

    MsgBox ("TopLeftCell: " & refPicture.TopLeftCell.Address)

    tempWidth = getCellWidth(refPicture.TopLeftCell)
    tempHeight = getCellHeight(refPicture.TopLeftCell)

    MsgBox ("Width and Height: " & tempWidth & " " & tempHeight)

    If tempWidth > tempHeight Then
        refPicture.Height = tempHeight
    Else
        refPicture.Width = tempWidth
    End If
End Function

Function getCellHeight(ByRef cellRef As Range) As Single
    curColumn = cellRef.Column
    curRow = cellRef.Row

    numOfRows = cellRef.MergeArea.Rows.Count
    totalHeight = 0

    MsgBox (cellRef.Address & " Rows: " & numOfRows)
    MsgBox ("Cell Height: " & cellRef.Height)
    For cRow = curRow To numOfRows
        MsgBox ("In Row For Loop")
        totalHeight = totalHeight + Cells(curColumn, cRow).Height
    Next

    getCellHeight = totalHeight
End Function

Function getCellWidth(ByRef cellRef As Range) As Single
    MsgBox (cellRef.Address)
    curColumn = cellRef.Column
    curRow = cellRef.Row

    numOfColumns = cellRef.MergeArea.Columns.Count
    totalWidth = 0

    For col = curColumn To numOfColumns
        MsgBox ("In Column For Loop")
        totalWidth = totalWidth + Cells(curRow, col).Width
    Next

    MsgBox (cellRef.Address & " Columns: " & numOfColumns)
    getCellWidth = totalWidth
End Function
```

Comment: `cellRef.MergeArea.Height` and `cellRef.MergeArea.Width` should work without needing to loop over the individual rows/columns

Comment: Thanks Tim, I feel ridiculous because I was using code from a different answer on a different website while I was at work and the loop is how they achieved the total width and height. I never thought to double check for a Width and Height attribute since they didn't have it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
Sub Tester()
    ResizeSingleImage ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
End Sub



Sub ResizeSingleImage(ByRef refPicture)

    Dim rng As Range, tempWidth, tempHeight
    Set rng = refPicture.TopLeftCell.MergeArea

    refPicture.Top = rng.Top
    refPicture.Left = rng.Left

    tempWidth = rng.Width
    tempHeight = rng.Height

    refPicture.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    'which dimension to resize?
    If tempWidth / refPicture.Width > tempHeight / refPicture.Height Then
        refPicture.Height = tempHeight
    Else
        refPicture.Width = tempWidth
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem with your original looping: let's say cellRef is **A5**

```
Function getCellHeight(ByRef cellRef As Range) As Single

    curColumn = cellRef.Column
    curRow = cellRef.Row                      '<< for A5 curRow = 5

    numOfRows = cellRef.MergeArea.Rows.Count  '<< let's say 4 rows
    totalHeight = 0

    MsgBox (cellRef.Address & " Rows: " & numOfRows)
    MsgBox ("Cell Height: " & cellRef.Height)


    For cRow = curRow To numOfRows  '<<<<this loops from 5 to 4....
        'code in loop doesn't execute....
        MsgBox ("In Row For Loop")
        totalHeight = totalHeight + Cells(curColumn, cRow).Height
    Next

    getCellHeight = totalHeight
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are two answers here, the first one is going to be the best solution, thanks to Tim Williams, the second is going to be the solution to the actual problem I was originally facing.

**The first (best) solution**

> Use .MergeArea.Height on the Range object.

It is quite obvious and is the most straightforward solution. I used the looping solution because when I originally looked up how to find the height and width of a merged cell, the loop was what came up through searches and I assumed properties didn't exist.

**The second solution using loop**

The issue is in the how the For-loop is setup. `For cRow = curRow To numOfRows` where `curRow` is the current row, making it so if you are at row 11 and the number of rows merged is only 3, the loop will never run. My solution to this was `For cRow = curRow To (curRow + numOfRows - 1)`. This will get you the same result, *but* it goes to show why the use of properties is preferred over re-building the wheel.